# Ubuntu - Run command on start-up

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I would like to run 2 commands when Ubuntu starts up(before anyone even logs in)

Also, these commands should be able to work, immediately after boot up. 
So how do I do this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to /etc/ and run

```
sudo nano rc.local
```

Place your commands below the comments, and above the command, "exit 0"

The commands should run on startup

Comment: Okay, there are other ways to do a startup command in this [article](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/run-command-startup-linux-27796.html). Have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299792/why-is-the-command-in-etc-rc-local-not-executed-during-startup) to see why rc.local isn't working. What commands are you trying to run?